# How can I say ‘poop’ in German for a cat (animal) in a funny but not rude way?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I wrote a cat book in English and am translating it into German right now (native German) but I can’t find a real good word for *poop*.

Comment: Can you post the sentence you want to translate? Some context is necessary when translating beyond mere definition.

Comment: Wenn du Muttersprachlerin bist, kannst du Fragen übrigens auch auf Deutsch stellen ;)

Comment: Wenn er muttersprachlic waere, wuerde nicht das Wort schon kennen?

Comment: @Mawg Ich wundere mich auch etwas, aber Christine sagt, sie sei "native German". I thought that meant "native speaker" and/or "mother tongue". Maybe we were wrong.

Comment: @Mawg Ach, ich hab öfters Wortfindungsstörungen … meistens geh ich dann ein englisches Wort suchen, gib das bei Leo ein und finde, was ich brauche. Oder ich frag das nächstbeste Opfer, das mir über den Weg läuft ;)

Comment: Ich habe das so gelesen, dass sie es in "native German", also "Deutsch in Muttersprachlerqualität", übersetzen möchte. Im Deutschen unterscheidet man ja auch zwischen Schulenglisch und authentischem Englisch.

Answer (score 25):

Häufchen, literally "little heap", it is what cat droppings are often referred to.

It is a naturally harmless and polite expression, so there's no danger of being rude. However, it is not very funny either.

P.S. "Häufchen" is usually not used to express dissatisfaction in the way "poop" often is. I guess it would be understood if someone did, and it would be kind of funny too.

Examples for proper usage have been posted as comment. I'm not putting them in my answer in order to avoid stealing the comment's votes. Thanks for the support, Phil.

Comment: Usage of the expression would normally be something along the lines of: "ein Häufchen machen" or "jemandem ein Häufchen hinterlassen"

Answer (score 3):

The only word that comes to my mind is "Kack**a**" (the 'a' at the end is important!). This is german baby talk and therefore sounds somehow funny. You can even find it on www.duden.de, marked as children language.

Comment: Unless it's a children's book, this sounds extremely cringeworthy.

Answer (score 3):

We sometimes use "Katzenküttel" or simply "Küttel". Depending on the dialect, it may be "Ködel" or "Köttel" as well.

"Küttel" as opposed to "Häufchen" signifies a dry small piece of excrement, and not a wet lump of poo.

Comment: _Wurst_ is another form of poo – longish and solid, sausage-like, as is typical for cats. I’d use _Köttel_ only for plentiful small droppings like the ones of rabbits, goats, mice or perhaps horses.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try something that is slightly humorous, but not a translation?

E.g.

> The cat had left me a little present. — Die Katze hatte mir ein kleines Geschenklein hinterlassen.

Comment: My first thought we be a dead bird or mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about the words: Kot / Exkrement / Ausscheidung(en)

Or which are rather funny: Köttel / Kacki (everything sounds cute / funny if you put an "i" behind it) / Brocken / Haufen (often used by some of my Friends "Ich hab einen riesen Brocken/Haufen gelegt").

Comment: "riesen" ist übrigens kein Adjektiv, und ein "i" macht übrigens nichts niedlich/lustig per se.

Answer (score 0):

Growing up in a German-speaking family, I've encountered various terms that at least by ear sound related to "poop":

- "Puh, das stinkt hier!"
- Puh-puh machen (small child talk for going to the toilet for "number 2")
- ... and then you get Pupsen, Pupse, Pupser which is related to farting. (The dictionary suggests to this non-expert that the original meaning of [poop](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/poop), silently breaking wind, was carried over (perhaps as euphemism) for passing wind (farting) and then to the passing of excreta. So perhaps wind-related terms would not be what you are looking for, or perhaps you could make it work.)
- **So perhaps something made-up like "pupu/puhpuh" would work for you**. *(It's unfortunate that in other languages words like [Pupu Kaka](https://www.facebook.com/kaka.pupu.3) make quite normal and honorable names.)*

As a expat German in another culture, it's hard for me to tell how widespread these would be understood.

Relating to pets, we would usually use the words "Mist", "Kot" or "Dreck". Fairly factual, with the connotation of "dirty, stay clear". Not really any cute sentimentality to it.

I guess it's interesting that other germanic languages also have similar-sounding words (["poep" in Dutch](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/dutch-english/poep), pronounced like "poop") with the same meaning. So I guess its not a recent word.

Answer (score -5):

Kacke - Katzen-Kacke

Kacke is the funny way of saying Scheiße

Comment: Is *Kacke* really funny? With *Kagge* as a derived form maybe, but *Kacke* in itself?

Comment: I don't think 'Kacke' is funny. If you say "Das ist Kacke!" you don't really want to make it sound funny.

Comment: Kacke is not intrinsically funny, but can be used in a funny manner. However, it can just as well be used in an annoyed, dismissive or aggressive manner.It really depends on the tone.

Comment: Additionally, it shouldn’t be spelled with a hyphen.